# Cloudant Query using $or operator gives warning - "no matching index found, create an index to optimize query time" though indexing is present?

Tags: couchdb, query-performance, cloudant

Cloudant Query using $or operator gives warning:

> “no matching index found, create an index to optimize query time”

though indexing is present? The sample information is shown below:

Index USED:

```
db.index({
ddoc: "document_id",
type: "json",
index: {
      fields: ["emailid", "mobileno"]
    }
});
```

Query USED:

```
selector: {
    $or: [
      {
        emailid: email_id
      },
      {
        mobileno: mobile
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find an issue in the couchdb project discussing something similar. ["$or operator slow"](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1852)

In the issue they conclude that the same field has to be present in both sides of the $or in order to select an index.

Your case doesn't meet this condition so the query will fall back into the _all_docs index (full scan of the db contents)